# First circle of R hell. 0.1 != 0.3/3

Tags: r, inequalities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Numeric comparison difficulty in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r)

Hello All,

According to ["R Inferno"](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) paper. I'm right now in the first circle of R hell. This is where pagans expect 0.1 == 0.3/3. Paper recommends using `all.equal` function for such cases, however I need to check ">=" or "<=" conditions. With current example on of them fail:

```
> .1 >= .3/3
[1] TRUE
> .1 <= .3/3
[1] FALSE
```

Is there a similar function to all.equal that checks inequalities?

Thank you,

Ilya

Comment: That's not an R specific error, but a common error that is caused by the binary representation of floating point numbers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems for example.

Comment: I know why error occurs. I would like to know if there is a R function that can check inequalities or I need to write one with floating points in mind.

Comment: yes, I need to do better searches

Comment: High popularity like for exact duplicate. Catchy title?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See these questions:

- [In R, what is the difference between these two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227734/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-these-two)
- [Numeric comparison difficulty in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r)

Generally speaking, you can deal with this by including a tolerance level as per the second link above.

Comment: See the second link which directly answers the question.

Comment: Thank you Shane, in second link I found your post with creating new operator - exactly what I wanted. Thank you!!

Comment: Duplicate identification belongs in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @dmckee.  I had made a comment to that effect.

Answer (score 10):

The main test of `all.equal` is whether `abs(x-y) < tolerance` for some values `x` and `y` and some small `tolerance`. Equivalent inequality tests would check:

```
x <= y:         x-y < tolerance
x < y:          x-y < -tolerance
x >= y:         x-y > -tolerance
x > y:          x-y > tolerance
```

Answer (score 6):

Please see the [R FAQ entry *Why doesn't R think these numbers are equal*](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and the references therein.

Comment: This is fascinating, but not an answer to the OP.

Comment: Sure is, or you read another entry 7.31. The example there is `sqrt(2)*sqrt(2) == 2` comes out as FALSE and is the same issue here: representation of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You could try judicious use of `zapsmall()` which seems to give the behavior you are looking for. I don't know if this works in all situations. e.g.,

```
.1 >= zapsmall(.3/3)
[1] TRUE
> .1 <= zapsmall(.3/3)
[1] TRUE
```