# R: all.equal vs all

Tags: r

I'm trying to test that two vectors are equal using both all and all.equal but they give different results and I'm not sure why.

```
> x = seq(0,1,by=0.2)
> x
[1] 0.0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0
 > y = c(0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0)
> all(x == y)
[1]  FALSE
> all.equal(x, y)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: It seems like `x == y` yields `[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE`.

Comment: Might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: `==` tests exact equality, whereas `all.equal` tests "near equality" to allow for floating point error.

Comment: Use `dplyr::near()` rather than `==` or `isTRUE(all.equal())`

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you've fallen into the [first circle of R hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079074/first-circle-of-r-hell-0-1-0-3-3), where floating point numbers don't behave as expected.

The misbehaving pair is x[4] & y[4] (as per coffeeinjunky's comment above). Look at them closely:

```
> print(c(x[4], y[4]))
[1] 0.6 0.6
> print(c(x[4], y[4]), digits = 16)
[1] 0.6000000000000001 0.6000000000000000
```

`all.equal` has a default tolerance level around 1.5e-8, & differences below this threshold are not reported. This is why `all.equal(x, y)` returns TRUE, while `all(x==y)` returns FALSE.

This post discusses the issue in more detail: [Numeric comparison difficulty in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769510/numeric-comparison-difficulty-in-r)