# join (plyr library), strange error

Tags: r, join

I'm trying to write a function in R that calculates a Gini score (coefficient of income inequality) for a given set of incomes and population shares. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
incomes <- c(1175,1520,1865,2210,2555) # incomes
population <- rep(1/5,5)*100           # population shares (5 times 1/5)

income <- incomes*population/sum(incomes*population) # income * frequency / total income
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(incomes,income,population/100))
names(data) <- c("incomes","income","population")

data <- data[order(as.numeric(data$incomes)),] # sort by percentage of income

for (i in 1:length(income)){
    data$richer[i] <- 1-sum(data$population[1:i])
}
data$score <- data$income * (data$population + 2 * data$richer)
gini <- round(1-sum(data$score),4) # gini
```

This all works well. But now I want to plot the income distribution and for this I make a new dataset:

```
data$population2 <- data$richer + data$population # cumulative
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(data=NA,ncol=1,nrow=20))
names(x) <- c("population2")
x$population2 <- rev(seq(0.05,1,0.05))

data.graph <- join(x, data, by = "population2")
```

so the 'data$population2' variable will have values of 1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2 and x$population2 will have values of 1, 0.95, 0.9, 0.85, 0.8, etc until 0.05. However, the join function only joins the values of 1, 0.8, 0.2, not 0.6 and 0.4 as it should! Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the [first circle of R hell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079074/first-circle-of-r-hell-0-1-0-3-3). :)

At one glance, all the values in `data$population2` look like they should have a match in `x$population2`:

```
> x$population2
 [1] 1.00 0.95 0.90 0.85 0.80 0.75 0.70 0.65 0.60 0.55 0.50 0.45 0.40 0.35 0.30 0.25 0.20 0.15 0.10 0.05
> data$population2
[1] 1.0 0.8 0.6 0.4 0.2
```

But that's not the case:

```
> x$population2[9]
[1] 0.6
> data$population2[3]
[1] 0.6

> data$population2[3] == x$population2[9]
[1] FALSE
> all.equal(data$population2[3], x$population2[9]) 
[1] TRUE
# all.equal tolerates numerical differences smaller than 1.5e-8 by default

> print(x$population2[9], digits = 20)
[1] 0.60000000000000009
> print(data$population2[3], digits = 20)
[1] 0.59999999999999987
```

The following will work for the sample case, though I'd caution against applying it in every scenario without taking into account how many decimal places of rounding is appropriate. In general, performing join with character keys is safer:

```
library(plyr); library(dplyr)

join(x %>% mutate(population2 = round(population2, 3)), 
     data%>% mutate(population2 = round(population2, 3)), 
     by = "population2")

   population2 incomes    income population richer      score
1         1.00    1175 0.1260054        0.2    0.8 0.22680965
2         0.95      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
3         0.90      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
4         0.85      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
5         0.80    1520 0.1630027        0.2    0.6 0.22820375
6         0.75      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
7         0.70      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
8         0.65      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
9         0.60    1865 0.2000000        0.2    0.4 0.20000000
10        0.55      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
11        0.50      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
12        0.45      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
13        0.40    2210 0.2369973        0.2    0.2 0.14219839
14        0.35      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
15        0.30      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
16        0.25      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
17        0.20    2555 0.2739946        0.2    0.0 0.05479893
18        0.15      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
19        0.10      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
20        0.05      NA        NA         NA     NA         NA
```

As a side note, instead using a for loop in your earlier step, you can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)

# use this
data <- data %>% mutate(richer = 1-cumsum(population))

# instead of this
for (i in 1:length(income)){
  data$richer[i] <- 1-sum(data$population[1:i])
}
```

For loop operations are relatively slow in R (noticeable in a larger dataset). R is optimised for vectorised operations.

Comment: Thank a lot! I was guessing it may have been a rounding error somewhere. Crazy :-) And also thanks a lot for the tip on replace the for loop (I should really learn how to use "the pipe")! I actually used your suggestion of applying as.character() to the vectors that should be used for joining the dataframes.