# Equal numbers shown as false when compared in R

Tags: r, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In R, what is the difference between these two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227734/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-these-two)
>   [floating point issue in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874867/floating-point-issue-in-r)

This is part of a code I created. I spend days looking for the problem when finally realized that a comparison that should be TRUE was being calculated by R as FALSE. I'm using R 2.14.2 64 bits on windows. This is the code to reproduce the problem.

```
concList= c(1.15, 1.15, 1.15 ,1.15 ,1.15 ,1.15 )
concList=concList-0.4
a=sum(concList)
b=length(concList)*0.75
str(a)
str(b)
print(a==b)
```

The last print will result in FALSE even thou they are shown as exactly the same number. I tough this could be some problem on the floating point numerical representation of R, so I added the code below which solves the problem.

```
a=round(a,1)
b=round(b,1)
print(a==b)
```

My question is, is there any more elegant solution? Is this a bug that should be reported?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Would `all.equal(a, b)` work for your purposes. This is different from `identical()` or what you have posted so far.

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874867/floating-point-issue-in-r

Comment: @csgillespie I saw that one too. I was certain there was another one with a fairly comprehensive answer; took me a few minutes to find it though.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because they aren't exactly the same number. They differ by a very small amount due to the computer's representation of numbers, also known as [floating point errors](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/):

```
> a - b
[1] -8.881784e-16
```

Jon Skeet has [an excellent blog post](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) on this issue, which pops up on Stack Overflow with [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011184/floating-point-comparison) [regularity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834028/i-read-it-on-jon-skeet-blog-and-now-i-want-to-know-the-answer).

As @mrdwab suggests in the comments, you should use `all.equal(a, b)` to test for *near* equality.

Comment: David has the point, see `?identical` for further assistance and examples.

Comment: The all.equal is the command I needed, thanks for the helpful response.